# How to specify a code dependency in a Drupal 7 module

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, dependencies, libraries

I'm currently working on making a Drupal module and I'm wondering if there's any mechanism for me to specify a github repository where upon installation, my module will obtain some code it depends on.

Important: What I'm depending on isn't itself a Drupal module as well, but just a library of code.  So unless it supports checking out github repos, I don't think the `dependencies` in my `info` file are going to help?

Comment: I haven't used it but [Composer Manager](https://drupal.org/project/composer_manager) should do the job

Comment: I'm familiar with composer and use it for other projects, but that would depend on my drupal project being set up with it which isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is no official way to manage external dependencies in Drupal 7.

But nothing (really) stop you to use a package manager like [bower](http://bower.io/) and [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

For composer their is two contrib projects:

- https://drupal.org/project/composer
- https://drupal.org/project/composer_manager

For Drupal 8, composer can be used to add dependencies to a Drupal project. Check the doc: [Using Composer in a Drupal project](https://www.drupal.org/node/2404989)

Answer (score 0):

Most projects seem to clearly list external library dependencies on their project pages, installation instructions and README files. Many use the libraries API to include dependencies and display configuration warnings if users haven't installed required libraries. Ckeditor, colorbox, and JSON2 all come to mind as examples.

UPDATE

No, the libraries module does not download dependencies. It simply provide an install location and means to include and use in modules. See the Libraries project page

Install the library module. Install the external dependence at sites/all/libraries.

First, register the library with hook_libraries_info().

```
/**
 * Implements hook_libraries_info().
 */
function mymodule_libraries_info() {
  $libraries['anet_php_sdk'] = array(
    'name' => 'Authorize.net PHP SDK',
    'vendor url' => 'https://developer.authorize.net/',
    'download url' => 'http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/',
    'version arguments' => array(
      'file' => 'README',
      'pattern' => '/Version (\d+)/',
      'lines' => 206,
      'version' => '1.1.8'
    ),
    'files' => array(
      'php' => array('AuthorizeNet.php'),
    ),
  );
  return $libraries;
}
```

Then include dependencies in your module.

```
/**
 * Assemble and send DPM payment request to Authorize.net.
 */
function mymodule_process_payment($reservation) {
  // Include/require the dependency using libraries_load().
  $library = libraries_load('anet_php_sdk');
  // Use the external dependency...
}
```

Visit the [libraries](http://drupal.org/projects/libraries) project page for additional documentation, including examples of requiring specific versions and handling checks and notifications.

Comment: Does the Libraries API allow for automatic download?  For example, if I make a module and put the external code it needs on github, can I have libraries fetch the code from github and set it up to be loaded?

Comment: No. I suppose most module developers don't want to deal with checking for and implementing the various possibilities available for downloading (i.e. Composer, Git, wget, curl, etc.).

Comment: Updated my answer to give an example of including Authorize.net's PHP SDK in a module.